# How can I judge a connection closed by server or client?

Tags: networking, go

I have a server which handle receiving data like this:

```
func handleRecv(conn *net.TCPConn) {
    header := make([]byte, 2)
    for {
        /**block until recieve len(header)**/
        n, err := io.ReadFull(conn, header)
        if err != nil {
             log.Error(err)
              break
        }
     }
 }
```

I would like to know  which the connnection is closed by ?   server or client according to `err` ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you're closing the connection locally, you should know about it in your code. Otherwise, receiving an `io.EOF` generally signals that the remote side initiated a close.

If `Close()` was called on the local side, you get a `*net.OpError` with the message `use of closed network connection`. You may want to just check for the `net.Error` interface, since that would theoretically cover more error conditions.

```
        if err, ok := err.(net.Error); ok {
            fmt.Error("not an io.EOF")
            fmt.Error(err.Error())
        }
```

This doesn't work however if `CloseRead()` was called on the local connection (which isn't very likely, but it has its uses).  That will return an `io.EOF`, and is why you still need to know what's happening to the connection locally.

If the connection was closed due to a timeout, you will get a `net.Error` indicating the timeout:

```
        if err, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && err.Timeout() {
            fmt.Error("timeout error")
        }
```

Finally, if you are concerned about the error returned, you may not want to use `io.Readfull`, which doesn't return `io.EOF` after a short read. Just read into your buffer and check the number of bytes read and the error yourself.